# Handle change event for all DevExtreme input widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, devexpress, devextreme

I am looking for a way to track if form fields have been modified using DevExtreme components. I thought I could bind all of them with a single event listener:

```
$('input').change(function () {
    console.log("Change detected.");
});
```

While this fires for ordinary `<input>` elements, the DevExtreme components (which all use an underlying hidden `<input>` element) do not. The components have an `onValueChanged` field that can have a function assigned, but the idea is to not have to do that to each and every control. I have forms with several dozen `dxTextBox`, `dxSelectBox`, `dxDateBox`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevExtreme widgets provide the [defaultOptions(rule)](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxTextBox/Methods/#defaultOptionsrule) method, which allows setting default configuration options for a specific component.

For example:

```
DevExpress.ui.dxTextBox.defaultOptions({ 
    device: { deviceType: "desktop" },
    options: {
        onValueChanged: function(e) {
           console.log("Change detected.");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is what I've ended up using, it has to be done for each widget type you use so repeat for `dxNumberBox`, `dxDateBox`, etc. Code can be simplified by assigning the same `options` object to each.

Answer (score 1):

> Event handlers attached using the delegate() method will work for both current and FUTURE elements (like a new element created by a script).

I would recommend [jQuery Delegate](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_delegate.asp) for this usage, even if it's deprecated it would help.